# how to format no line break json file?

Tags: java, json

This is a continue question by [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859000/format-json-file-with-comma).
Now the problem is, there is no line break in each line. All data stick together, how can I do that?
Like this:

```
{"bla":"bla"}{"bla":"bla"}{"bla":"bla"}{"bla":"bla"}{"bla":"bla"}{"bla":"bla"}.....
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to do this to view it or in your application because there are web sites that can format it for you http://jsonlint.com/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read in the JSON file as a single String and replace "}{" with "}\n{".  Pass the resulting String into a StringReader and you can read it line by line.